# Get unique results from observable

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I have a `component` that fetches data from a service and pushes data to an array upon button click. If that data already exists in the array, I don't want it to be pushed again.

```
import { ImportResults } from '../shared/mass.interface';
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MassEmpService } from '../shared/mass.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-employee-selection',
    templateUrl: './employee-selection.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./employee-selection.component.css']
})

export class EmployeeSelectionComponent implements OnInit {

    // Define our search results
    public searchResults: ImportResults[] = [];

    constructor(
        private _massEmpService: MassEmpService
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        // Push our results to the array if they don't already exist
        this._massEmpService.importedResults.subscribe(
            data => (this.searchResults.indexOf(data) === -1 ? this.searchResults.push(...data) : '')
        );

    }
}
```

Is there any quick way to test if an identical object already exists in an array without having to look for a specific key or value?

**Scenario**

I enter a username into a search field and press "search". It provides me the results, I push them to an array and then use `*ngFor` to loop over them and display them. However, if I then searched by supervisor, I don't want anyone thats already in the results to appear again, only new data that has not yet been seen.

I know this is more of a generic Javascript question but I am curious if ES6 or angular has anything short that will accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) and [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method.

The code would be something like that:

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
/*
  rest of your code
*/

export class EmployeeSelectionComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        // Push our results to the array if they don't already exist
        this._massEmpService.importedResults.subscribe(data => {
             if (this.searchResults.findIndex(elem => _.isEqual(elem,data)) == -1)
                 this.searchResults.push(data);
        });    
    }
/*
  rest of your code
*/
}
```

Other solution would be to use [`.filter()` method](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html), but here you need to traverse all entries as well:

```
ngOnInit() {
   // Push our results to the array if they don't already exist
   this._massEmpService.importedResults.filter(data => {
             return this.searchResults.findIndex(elem => _.isEqual(elem,data)) == -1})
        .subscribe(data => this.searchResults.push(data));    
}
```

I think it could be also good, to immediatelly reject objects with the same reference:

```
 this._massEmpService.importedResults.filter(data => data != data).... //another chain here
```

You could also try to experiment with `_.indexOf`: http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf

Comment: This may do the trick - Do you know if rxjs offers anything comparable to the underscore library in terms of this function/solution? I try to avoid needing to install a dependency for a one time use function but mayb need to do so.

Comment: I don't think so. The only other way which I see is to use .filter() method. But again you will need to go threw whole array and compare every element. I will update my answer with this solution in minutes.

Comment: No, RxJS doesn't have any functions related to deep comparison, you always need to provide your own filter function

Comment: Strange, I installed underscore and used both of the above code snippets and my final output still gets duplicated.

Comment: Ohh. Try to `console.log(_.isEqual(object1, object2))`. What is the output?

Comment: @MaciejTreder - Sorry just getting back to this, was in a meeting. What are my two objects in this case? I tried `console.log(_.isEqual(this.searchResults, data))` and I am getting `false` back in the console.

Comment: As far as I understand under this.searchResults you have **array**, and you are looking for **item**. Maybe that's the case? :) If you want to find item in array you can use _.indexOf(): http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf

Answer (score 0):

try below myaaray is your array wityh duplicate entries and uniue array will contain array without duplicate entries

```
var unique = myArray.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
```

Comment: Is this method doing deep compare, or just only comparing references?

Comment: this is not doing deep compare\

Comment: @RahulCv You can use this approach recursively for deep comparison.